# How to implement Neville's algorithm for 4 control-points to get non-bijective polynome?

Tags: algorithm, processing

I'm preparing a short presentation on how Neville's algorithm works as an assignment for numerical analysis class and since it's an algorithm widely used in computer science for interpolation through several control-points, I thought implementing it is a good idea for demonstration. Now, I've chosen to do it for 4 control-points (in Processing language) and this is what I get: [bijective polynome](http://prntscr.com/4zfxyy)

whereas I wanted to get this (taken from jsxgraph site):

[non-bijective polynome](http://prntscr.com/4zfyso)

My plotting function is as below:

```
//Draggable is the class which defines x,y and r of a point and contains methods Draggable::coordx() and Draggable::coordy()
//for fetching x and y of a point, nizd below is an array of points, consider them to be already set on stage when Neville() is called

Draggable[] nizd = new Draggable[4];
float[][] P = new float[4][4];  //matrix used for dynamic solution

void Neville () {
   for (int i=0; i<3; i++)                        //this is where point are sorted according 
     for (int j=i+1; j<4; j++)                    //to their x-coordinate in ascending order
       if (nizd[j].coordx()<nizd[i].coordx()) {   //just in case they overlap
         Draggable temp = nizd[i];                //if I haven't done it, polynome would just
         nizd[i] = nizd[j];                       //not be plotted between not sorted points
         nizd[j] = temp;                          //and that's what I don't want
       }

   float pretx, prety; // variables used for memorizing coordinates of a previous pixel

   for (int i=0; i<4; i++) //setting the first column of the matrix with known y-coordinates
      P[i][0] = nizd[i].coordy();

   pretx = nizd[0].coordx();
   prety = nizd[0].coordy();

   for (int x = nizd[0].coordx(); x<= nizd[3].coordx(); x++) {    //loop that calculates the matrix P for every pixel between all 4 points
      for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) 
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) 
          P[i][j] = ((x*1.0 - nizd[i - j].coordx())*(P[i][j - 1]) 
                    - (x*1.0 - nizd[i].coordx())*(P[i - 1][j - 1]))/(nizd[i].coordx()*1.0 -         nizd[i - j].coordx());

   line (pretx, prety, x, P[3][4]);
   pretx = x;
   prety = P[3][5];
   }

}
```

So, I want to get that second, rope-like polynome preserving the order of points and not needing to sort them over and over again. I would appreciate any help. Thanks!